# Horizontal and Vertical alignment of a toolbar with Bootstrap elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a page header / tool bar.  This in an existing theme and there is a DIV at the top where this will reside.  The basic premise is on the left a H2 title then on the right a bunch of bootstrap elements (search form, bottons, dropdowns etc.

I have tried all kinds of block, inline-block vertical-align etc.  I can get the H2 to pull left and the toolbar to pull right but the toolbar elements all pull up to the top of the container div.  I just want a clean looking layout with all the elements aligned along their horizontal axis.

I think the pull-right may be part of the problem.  That seems to pull the right div up to the top.

Here is a Bootply link: http://www.bootply.com/BPucyP8mpk

```
<div class"container">    
<div id="left">
      <h2 class="">Title</h2>

</div>

<div id="right">
  <form class="form form-horizontal">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search field" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn">search</button>
  </form>
  <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Left</button>
    <button class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button class="btn">Right</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="">Choice1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">Choice2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">Choice3</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="">Choice..</a>


     </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is the computed CSS that wraps the header I am trying to format:

```
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(103, 106, 108);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(103, 106, 108);
display: block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
height: 70px;
line-height: 18px;
margin-left: -15px;
margin-right: -15px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 1318px;
```

This is from my custom theme I have installed.  This is the computed CSS from this wrapper div:

```
 <div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
 </div>
```

Comment: why you don't use col-md-* class for it

Comment: I have that (like the answer below) now but my concern (that may perhaps should not be a big deal) is that if I do a col-lg-4 / col-lg-8 or a col-lg-2 / col-lg-10 etc. the left column can cause the title to wrap (I have some font awesome icons etc.) or the toolbar ends up too small.

Comment: what is the problem show in http://www.bootply.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD:

**The most suitable method for this task is use Flexbox**

Check it out: http://www.bootply.com/CtVmUbzrlr

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="left" class="col-sm-3 col-md-5">
      <h2 class="">Title</h2>
    </div>

 <div id="right" class="col-sm-9 col-md-7">


   <form class="form form-horizontal">
     <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" placeholder="search field" class="form-control">
       <span type="submit" class="input-group-addon">search</span>
     </div>
   </form>

   <button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>

   <div class="btn-group">
     <button class="btn">Left</button>
     <button class="btn">Middle</button>
     <button class="btn">Right</button>
   </div>

   <div class="btn-group"><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#" class="">Choice1</a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#" class="">Choice2</a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#" class="">Choice3</a>
       </li>
       <li class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#" class="">Choice..</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div>

</div>

  </div>
```

---

```
.row{
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#right{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 66px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.input-group{
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: That is so close to what I want.  See my update above.  My only question is the height: 66px;.  Like all other solutions you seem to need to hard code that height or add padding to push the right pulled div down from the top of the container.  The ideal solution would be to set the height of the wrapper container and have the elements inside auto margin but I am getting the impression that is really not possible.

Comment: It is possible. Just add display: flex; to the container. http://www.bootply.com/2GvxoyRkUa

Comment: That works perfect.  The only downside I see is that the element do not wrap well on small screens.  I may have to look at a hybrid nav-bar solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <h2 class="">Title</h2>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8">
  <div class="row">
<form class="form form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search field" class="form-control">
  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block">search</button>
  </div>
</form>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
<button class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn">Left</button>
    <button class="btn">Middle</button>
    <button class="btn">Right</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group"><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="">Choice1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="">Choice2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="">Choice3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="">Choice..</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

you can check bootply also : http://www.bootply.com/LmGjZM6fHH
You need to manage your layout with the col-md-*
This is just for the demo, you can arrange with you own way

Answer (score 1):

What about utilizing the navbar component from bootstrap?
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar
I think the example here pretty much sums up your needs.

Basically I've added classes `navbar-btn` to the buttons, and `navbar-form` to the form to get them to align properly. I added the class `navbar-right` to both the form and the group of buttons.
http://www.bootply.com/IySnkX2ioK

Edit: The `navbar-default` class was just added to outline the bounds of the navbar, not part of the solution.

Comment: It's close - the issue always seems to be when you pull that toolbar right it wants to ignore the vertical align etc. and it pulls to the top.  Padding would fix it but I was hoping for a solution that didn't require that.  If you change the height of the container around it you have to adjust the padding.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that if you want to have your search box on left - place it first and then button group with dropdown. Second, don't place `navbar-rigth` inside another `navbar-rigth`. And the last thing - just wrap your right-side elements in one `div` and add to it a little `padding`

Updated [link](http://www.bootply.com/VLe8lIc3Hk)